# Fuente de letras para un Textview

Tags: android, textview, fuentes

Necesito cambiar la fuente de un `Textview`. Mi pregunta es la siguiente las fuentes para las letras son especiales para android o sirve una estándar. Me sugieren alguna libreria o pagina de descarga de fuentes, gracias.

Por ejemplo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Colocare mi `Textview` para que no sea basada en opiniones :p

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="CARROS A PEDALES"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="21dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Recomiendo que leas en la doc de Android: [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html)

Comment: @A.Cedano ese material es para < Android 8 segun leo ...

Comment: No, es al contrario, para Android 8.0+ , o sea, API 26 en adelante: _(API nivel 26) y Android Support Library 26 introducen soporte para API para solicitar fuentes de una aplicación al proveedor en lugar de agrupar archivos en el APK o dejar que las fuentes sean descargas por la APK. La función está disponible en dispositivos que ejecutan versiones API de Android 14 y superiores a través de la Biblioteca de soporte 26._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma es colocando los archivos ttf en un folder dentro de Assets.
Para crear el folder `assets`:
click derecho en `app`: New, Folder, Assets Folder, Target Source Set:main, Finish. Una vez creado assets click derecho en el: `Show in Explorer`, abres el folder de assets, creas el folder fonts y allí pegas los archivos ttf

Y en java es donde configuras el textView:

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MoonLight Regular.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta !